# How to create Signature from &str?

Tags: subxt, keyring

I'm trying to create a basic HTTP server that authorizes users with `Authorization Pubkey:Sig` like what Crust explained [here](https://wiki.crust.network/docs/en/buildIPFSWeb3AuthGW#solution).

However, creating a `Signature` from `&str` with `Signature::fromSlice()` failing. How can I convert the `&str` to a `Signature`?

```rust
pub type Signature = subxt::sp_core::sr25519::Signature;
pub type PublicKey = subxt::sp_core::sr25519::Public;
```

```rust
let pub_key = value.get(0).unwrap(); // 5GrwvaEF5zXb26Fz9rcQpDWS57CtERHpNehXCPcNoHGKutQY
let sig = value.get(1).unwrap(); // f2f7211fcc2204dc3fa50cf1aca98b7c49c82510efbc84fd808b46c459069017db7a47acf4040d1cc0363eb5e3416c197e15fd2439e70a69dcdfa2eb8b520280
let public_key = PublicKey::from_str(pub_key);
let signature = Signature::from_slice(sig.as_bytes());

if public_key.is_err() {
    return Err(actix_web::error::ErrorUnauthorized("Invalid Public Key"));
}

if signature.is_none() {
    return Err(actix_web::error::ErrorUnauthorized("Invalid Signature"));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that `sig` you're getting from `value.get(1).unwrap()` is correct?

[documentation](https://docs.rs/sp-runtime/6.0.0/sp_runtime/testing/sr25519/struct.Signature.html) on `from_slice` says the following:

> A new instance from the given slice that should be 64 bytes long.
> NOTE: No checking goes on to ensure this is a real signature. Only use it if you are certain that the array actually is a signature. GIGO!

also, checking your code:

```
let sig = "f2f7211fcc2204dc3fa50cf1aca98b7c49c82510efbc84fd808b46c459069017db7a47acf4040d1cc0363eb5e3416c197e15fd2439e70a69dcdfa2eb8b520280";
println!("{}", sig.as_bytes().len());
```

prints out `128`, which is 2x the expected.

if I cut it down to half:

```
let sig = "f2f7211fcc2204dc3fa50cf1aca98b7c49c82510efbc84fd808b46c459069017";
let signature = Signature::from_slice(sig.as_bytes());
println!("{:?}", signature);
```

I get:

`Some(66326637323131666363323230346463336661353063663161636139386237633439633832353130656662633834666438303862343663343539303639303137)`

Which doesn't necessarily mean that you should also cut down in half whatever is coming from `value.get(1).unwrap()`. But it does mean that for some reason, this value is 2x bigger than a correct signature would be.

Comment: I signed Alice's public key using https://polkadot.js.org/apps/#/signing. I',m sure that `sig` is what I send with the header. After signing, I send the combination as a header using Postman. I guess I need to use a client library that can create a 64-byes long signature.